# Git: ERROR: Unable to determine version

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, svn2git

I'm trying to convert some svn-repo's to git (Atlassian Stash) using [this tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview/) of Atlassian itself. When I run the command

```
java -jar svn-migration-scripts.jar verify
```

I get following result:

```
svn-migration-scripts: using version 0.1.56bbc7f
Git: ERROR: Unable to determine version.
Subversion: using version 1.9.3
```

But I already have a working version of git:

```
git --version
git version 2.8.0.windows.1
```

I did some googling but nobody seems to have an answer to this problem so I thought I'll give it a try here. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a one-time conversion and only git is used afterwards, or do you want to commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Comment: Did you follow the step to `SET LANG=C` if there is a problem with determining version?

Comment: I did follow the step SET LANG=C but no success.. And I want to use git afterwards instead of svn (I still will have to use svn for other projects tho).

Comment: Also I've tried running the commandline as admin and doing all the steps again, again same thing.

Answer (score 1):

That migration script uses `git-svn` under the hood, but `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files. And as it needs the repository files locally anyway, you have the best pre-requisites.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for that clear and complete response! I will check it out and get back to you about the result (have to do this in between my other work so it can take a little while).